# How can I detect window resize event using Win32::GUI and WM_DISPLAYCHANGE?

Tags: perl, winapi, win32gui

I am struggling to make a simple receive `WM_DISPLAYCHANGE` informing my [Win32::GUI](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::GUI) app that the Windows Screen Resolution has changed, since the results for this question here is "0" accordingly informed by the search engine.

Could you provide a simple working example of a simple `Win32::GUI` program that detects a `WM_DISPLAYCHANGE` message and prints some info about that change in resolution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From user "beech" at PerlMonks: http://perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=1171819

> Try using the [Hook](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Win32-GUI/GENERATED/Win32/GUI/Reference/Methods.pod#Hook) method:
>
> something like
>
> ```
> $main->Hook( WM_DISPLAYCHANGE(), \&onDisplayChange );
> sub onDisplayChange {
>     my( $object, $wParam, $lParam, $type, $msgcode) = @_;
>     print "Click handler called!\n";
> }
> ```

Comment: When quoting, it would be nice to provide a reference alongside proper attribution. Otherwise it will look like plagiarism.

Answer (score 0):

Give a name to your window. Let's call it `Main`.

```
$main = Win32::GUI::Window->new(
                -name   => 'Main',
                -width  => 100,
                -height => 100,
        );
```

Now, define an event handler for the window. It should be of below pattern:

```
<window name>_<event name>
```

For example, for Resize event the event handler should be Main_Resize.

```
sub Main_Resize {
    my $mw = $main->ScaleWidth();
    my $mh = $main->ScaleHeight();
    my $lw = $label->Width();
    my $lh = $label->Height();
    #print the height/width or whatever you want
}
```

I would suggest going through [Win32::GUI::Tutorial](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::GUI::Tutorial).

Comment: This doesn't address the question. Please pay attention, when editing a question to not ask a different one. The question is (was) asking about receiving the [WM_DISPLAYCHANGE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145210.aspx) message.

Comment: Hi Chankey, thanks for your interest in this matter. 
WM_DISPLAYCHANGE is a message sent by Windows through the system to inform a screen resolution change. For example: change your screen resolution from 1024x768 to 800x600, then WM_DISPLAYCHANGE is sent. I am trying to detect inside a Win32::GUI perl app.